# How can I automatically resize any div height and width depend on mouse pointer movement?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

here is my div look like
[image]

I found few topics on stack overflow but didn't understand properly how to apply on my project. assume if I take mouse pointer between of column1 and column2 then I want an arrow will be show and depend on my mouse left or light it will adjust the width and also if I take my mouse pointer between column2 and column3 I want the height of column2 and column3 will be automatically adjusted. here my react code

```
const test = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="column1">
        <div className="content">
          <h2>Column 1</h2>
          {/* Add content for Column 1 here */}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="column2">
        <div className="content">
          <h2>Column 2</h2>
          {/* Add content for Column 2 here */}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="column3">
        <div className="content">
          <h2>Column 3</h2>
          {/* Add content for Column 3 here */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

my css

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  /* Adjust the grid-template-columns to allocate less space to the first column */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr; /* You can adjust the values as needed */
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.column1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.column2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.column3 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: `automatically adjusted`  adjusted to what, are you on about creating a splitter for resizing, like if you wanted to resize the tree view in VS/Code.?

Comment: Keit like if I take mouse pointer between column A and B then if I keep taking my mouse pointer from left to right then it will keep increasing width of column A and decreasing width of column B something like that until I left my mouse pointer. If my mouse pointer under between two column it will adjust the height

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a splitter, but don't you mouse down between A & B first to start the resize, and when you mouse up it stops.  IOW: like this -> https://split.js.org/

Comment: I'd add some transparent elements between the columns, so it's easier to understand which columns should be affected, then just listen for the mouse button down event on those elements, and after that check mouse movement. You'll need to handle some edge cases + consider using width/height instead of the grid for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

you can use react-split library as pointed out by Keith
here is an example on how you can achieve what you asking above

```
import Split from 'react-split';

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <Split
      sizes={[30, 40, 30]} // Initial column sizes in percentages
      minSize={100} // Minimum size for columns
      expandToMin={false} // Disable expanding columns to their minimum size
      gutterSize={10} // Size of the draggable gutter
      gutterAlign="center" // Align the gutter to the center
    >
      <div className="column1">
        <div className="content">
          <h2>Column 1</h2>
          {/* Add content for Column 1 here */}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="column2">
        <div className="content">
          <h2>Column 2</h2>
          {/* Add content for Column 2 here */}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="column3">
        <div className="content">
          <h2>Column 3</h2>
          {/* Add content for Column 3 here */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Split>
  );
};
```